# Add more videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube-api

I have the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="player2"></div>

    <script>

        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player2;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
                height: '360',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'mRBaAYdJuLY',
            });
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It works great but I need add two more videos and have no idea how. I read the documentation but have not found anything that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they follow the same format, you'd just need to add a third `<div>` element with the ID `player3`, and then update the JavaScript to reflect `#player2` and `#player3`. Obviously you'd also need to alter the video URL.

This can be seen in the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="player2"></div>
    <div id="player3"></div>

    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        var player2;
        var player3;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '360',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'mRBaAYdJuLY',
            });
            player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
                height: '360',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'ID2', // Replace this
            });
            player3 = new YT.Player('player3', {
                height: '360',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'ID3', // Replace this
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```